# Exception handing , how does it work in this case

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I have a Class A with Object of type Class B returning an Object , In what case will I get a null ? If there is an exception in test , in which I use an external api and an exception is thrown shouldn't the control go to the outer Class A ?
I am getting a Null pointer exception in this line -> ob.toString();
Unable to understand this.
Thank you for your help in advance

```
Class A{
   try{
      B b = new B();
      UserDefinedObject ob = b.test();
      ob.count();
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
    }
}

Class B {
    try{
     UserDefinedObject test(){
       return object;
     }
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
      throw ex;
    }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: how many reasons do you want that if this is java code it won't compile, let alone run?

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile. So please add proper code (also this has nothing to do with Spring nor Spring Boot, so I removed those tags, as this is just a regular Java question).

Comment: May be I did a poor job in illustrating this , this code does compile I have a class annotated with component and I call it from class A which encloses the calling class B in a try catch block , I however am getting a null returned

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact code you provided is incorrect and not compilable, *return null* statement there is unreachable code. So you need to be sure that the object you return is not null. If to make it executable and cleaner, for example:

```
public class A {

  public static void main(String []args){
     B b = new B();
     try{
       Object ob = b.test();
       System.out.println("Result: " + ob.toString());
     } catch(Exception ex){
       System.out.println("Failed in parent call");
     }
  }
 
 
  static class B {
     Object test(){
       try{
         return new String("B");
       } catch(Exception ex){
         System.out.println("Failed in B class");
         throw ex;
       }
     }
   }

}
```

As *Object* I took *new String("B")* just to simplify code.
In B there're only 2 exit points: return statement in test method and exception block, any code after exception block will be unreachable. If *new String("B")* produces *Exception* it will be caught in *B.test()* and pass up to *A.main()*. Hope it added a bit of light here.

Comment: thank you Yaro , this makes it clear . I will do a better job of presenting the question the next time around